# Configurable Product with associated individual product doesn't show

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, importexport

When I change the configurable options in the drop down menu, it changes only price. But it doesn't change such as sku, description, additional info of associated simple products. It was worked well before. I think it happens after I upgraded magento into 1.9.2.2 . please help me about this issue. please check this link and change the configurable option ( size ), then you can see only change price. But it doesn't show actual simple's details such as sku, description. https://www.bestdeals4ever.com/double-wind-spinner.html thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not the default behaviour of Magento. It will not load a simple products description etc if this is selected using the product options.

To do what you're needing you would need to use an extension such as Simple Configurable Products. The github for which is available here:https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

Comment: But it was worked well with 1.9.2.1 . According to this article , there are lots of incompatibility : http://codingbasics.net/magento-extensions-that-will-break-with-supee-6788/. There has to be show different images for each option such as color or size. Before I used multiple images ( for simples different images )

Comment: @sanj This is not default functionality. If it worked before, it was by some extension or custom code.

Comment: It worked after I use flat catelog function.

Comment: Again, this is likely due to an issue with an extension. The functionality really isn't default Magento behaviour.